# How to identify a repetitive type of pattern with regex (c#)

Tags: c#, regex

Currently I'm doing:

```
Regex.Match(ln, "\"[\\u0000-\\u007E]+\"")
```

The problem is if `ln` is like ""*text...*"" it won't work as wanted.

Same to """*text...*""", etc...

How can I make the " " repetitive?

It should also match to "*text1*"*text2*"*text3*".

The point is, it should match with the most 2 outer " " if the number of " is par or cut the last " if number impar.

Ex: `"stack"overflow"` -> match `"stack"`

Ex: `"stack""overflow"` -> match `"stack""overflow"`

Ex: `text1""text2""text3` -> match `""text2""`

Ex: `"text1"text2"text3` -> match `"text1"`

Any idea how to make this pattern?

Comment: Maybe something like [`"[^"]*"(?:[^"]*"[^"]*")*`](https://regex101.com/r/lZdKZf/1)

Comment: ```text1""text2""text3``` is ```""text2""``` but not ```"text2"``` ?

Comment: @bobblebubble i think it works, if you want answer the question.

Comment: Why ```[\\u0000-\\u007E]``` is this only number?

Comment: @MichaelMao yes, i need to know how many " were used

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An idea is to work with [negated](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated) `"` between.

- Match `"[^"]*"`
- [Repeat](https://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) `[^"]*"[^"]*"` any amount of times

```
"[^"]*"(?:[^"]*"[^"]*")*
```

[See this demo at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/lZdKZf/1) (the `\n` in multiline demo is for staying in line)

Comment: If i wanted to add [\\u0000-\\u007E]+ where would i put it?

Comment: @Filipe I guess this range contains `"` so that would not work. You would probably need to replace each `[^"]` with `[\u0000-\u0021\u0023-\u007E]` like [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/aCtVII/1).